# how to add Jenkins job parameters into system variable of a windows PC

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to figure a way to add my Jenkins job parameters displayed in job configure page into slave node (windows PC).

So meanwhile if anyone know How to add Jenkins job parameters into system variable of a windows PC.

Please do share it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following use case:

> You set up a test job on Jenkins, and it accepts a distribution bundle
>   as a parameter and perform tests against it. You want to have
>   developers do local builds and let them submit builds for test
>   execution
>   on Jenkins. In such a case, your parameter is a zip file that contains
>   a distribution.
>
> Your test suite takes so much time to run that in normal execution you
>   can't afford to run the entire test cycle. So you want to control the
>   portion of the test to be executed. In such a case, your parameter is
>   perhaps a string token that indicates that test suite to be run. The
>   parameters are available as environment variables. So e.g. a shell
>   ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

Example:

```
my.prop=${env.BAR}
```

More info at [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)